# How to use return status value for grep?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, grep, tail

Why isn't my command returning "0"?

```
grep 'Unable' check_error_output.txt && echo $? | tail -1
```

If I remove the 'echo $?' and use tail to get the last occurrence of 'Unable' in check_error_output.txt it returns correctly. If I remove the tail -1, or replace it the pipe with && it returns as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand how it will be useful in this scenario? Essentially, I'm trying to get the return status of my command to use in my script.

Comment: ah I see ok - you're title is a little misleading haha :) let me change for yas

Comment: What are you trying to do? find an occurrence of "Unable" in the last line of the file?

Comment: I'm trying to check whether 'Unable' exists in a file via grep, and only return the output of $? so that I can use that output in an if statement in my bash script

Comment: Please take a look at my answer then, it achieves just that in a clean way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding brackets around the grep and $?

```
(grep 'Unable' check_error_output.txt && echo $?) | tail -1
```

Answer (score 1):

The following way achieves what you're wanting to do without the use of pipes or sub shells

`grep -q 'Unable' check_error_output.txt && echo $?`

The -q flag stands for quiet / silent

From the man pages:

> Quiet;  do  not  write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.  Also
>                 see the -s or --no-messages option.  (-q is specified by POSIX.)

This is still not fail safe since a "No such file or directory" error will still come up both ways.

**I would instead suggest the following approach, since it will output either type of return values:**

```
grep -q 'Unable' check_error_output.txt 2> /dev/null; echo $?
```

The main difference is that regardless of whether it fails or succeeds, you will still get the return code and error messages will be directed to /dev/null. Notice how I use ";" rather than "&&", making it echo either type of return value.

Comment: I would also like to know whether the output returns as 1 for my if statement, see my comment above to @Raman Sailopal

Comment: The second bit of code, under my suggested approach does just that, it will output ANY return code for grep.

Comment: Thanks for the comment/answer @UlisesAndréFierro - This works exactly as I wanted via command line. However I'm having other issues with my script now, specifically echo'ing from my if statement depending on the return code (0 or 1), it always produces the echo which corresponds to return code 1 no matter what

Please see my section of code here: 

outputfile=/example/folder/structure/check_error_output.txt

if [ "grep -q 'Unable' $outputfile && echo $?" = "0" ]; then
    echo -e "ERROR MESSAGE FOUND"
else
    echo -e "NO ERROR MESSAGES HAVE BEEN FOUND"
fi

Comment: You'll probably be better off asking another question, but try using $( grep -q 'Unable' $outputfile && echo $?)  instead of quotes. The quotes won't expand, whatever is inside of $() will.

Answer (score 0):

use process Substitution:

```
cat <(grep 'Unable' check_error_output.txt) <(echo $?) | tail -1
```

Comment: This seems a little too bloated for what OP is trying to achieve. I believe neither process substitution nor pipes are necessary in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check the return value of any command in an if statement is: `if cmd; then`.  For example:

```
if grep -q 'Unable' check_error_output.txt; then ...
```